# iOS Swift API URLQueryitem

Tags: ios, urlcomponents

```
var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/")
    urlComponents?.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "id", value: userId.id)]

 var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/")
    urlComponents?.queryItems = [URLQueryItem(name: "id", value: userId.id)]
    
    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: (urlComponents?.url!)!)
    urlRequest.httpMethod = "GET"
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    let session = URLSession(configuration: config)
    
    print("urlRequest=====\(urlRequest)")
    
    session.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { (data, response, error) in
        
        guard let data = data else { return }
        
        do {
            let decoder = JSONDecoder()
            let userRes = try decoder.decode([UserResponse].self, from: data)
            self.delegate?.UserDetailsSuccess(userDetail: userRes)
        } catch let error {
            print("Error: ", error)
        }
    }.resume()
```

I am getting the url as : urlRequest=====https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/?id=1
The actual url : https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1

I need to remove the ?id=
How to remove this characters from this. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I reverted your latest edit because the question became pointless. The string must be `"https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/\(userId.id)"` with a backslash before the  `(`. If it still crashes then something is wrong with `userId`. Is it optional?

Comment: no userId is not optional

Comment: Then just `print("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/\(userId.id)")` to see what you get

Comment: in model class id was optional. I removed that now it is working fine. 
thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`URLQueryItem` adds the question mark which represents the query separator.

This REST URL doesn't use URL query so `URLQueryItem` is not needed at all. Add the user ID with String Interpolation.

`URLRequest` is not needed either, GET is the default and you don't use a special configuration

```
let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/\(userId.id)")!

URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
    
    if let error { print(error); return }
    
    do {
        let decoder = JSONDecoder()
        let userRes = try decoder.decode([UserResponse].self, from: data!)
        self.delegate?.UserDetailsSuccess(userDetail: userRes)
    } catch {
        print("Error: ", error)
    }
}.resume()
```

Comment: So, where we need to use URLQueryItem?

Comment: If I am giving like above code, app is crashing Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

in this line         let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/\(userId.id)")!

Comment: Please note the backslash (\\) before the opening parenthesis. `URLQueryItem` is needed if the URL contains the query like many Google APIs.

Comment: I gave backslash, but it is not showing when I post a comment.
let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/\(userId.id)")!

Comment: Put code always in backticks (\`)

Comment: `let url = URL(string: "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/\(userId.id)")!`
Thanks. Now you can see. still it is crashing and userId is not in optional